trying to make a simple if-else c code but it's not working as intended (assignment inside if)
I'm new to c code and I'm currently trying to make an if-else statement. but my code only prints out the first condition regardless of the answer I type in. What is the issue?
Here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char choice;

    printf("are you handsome? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    if (choice='y') {
        printf("you are clearly lying");
    }
    else if (choice='n') {
        printf("i'm glad you're being honest :D");
    }
    else {
        printf("you're not following instructions");
    }
    return 0;
}


choice='y' does not compare choice to 'y'. It assigns 'y' to choice.

I'm finding it unbelivable I can't find a good dupe target.

dupe of C - compare read in float to zero amongst many others

Welcome to SO. You should turn up your compiler warnings. It should warn you about a probably unintented assignment in a condition. You should generally turn up warnings. They are a valuable help.

@Gerhardh Beware GCC's -Wparentheses though - it can fail to warn about the assignment when the conditional clause is complex with multiple levels of parentheses.  Because of that, in a lot of ways -Wparentheses is worse than useless because it engenders a false sense of protection against bugs like the one in this question.  And it fails where it's most needed - in complex code.

@AndrewHenle It may be useless for complex code but for people struggling already with simple code it should be sufficiently helpful

In C and C++, the = operator means assignment. So in your code, you are assigning 'y' to choice, so choice now acquires a non-zero value and equates to true.
Try using the equivalence operator == instead:
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   char choice;

   printf("are you handsome? (y or n): ");
   scanf("%c", &choice);

   if (choice == 'y') {
      printf("you are clearly lying");
   }
   else if (choice == 'n') {
      printf("i'm glad you're being honest :D");
   }
   else {
      printf("you're not following instructions");
   }
   return 0;
}


Thank you for answering! I can't believe i missed such a simple thing hahhaha. I'll do my best next time.
